# removable(draggable) and replaceable DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, draggable, movable

I want to create some `<div>`s. I want to be able to move and replace these Divs.
I think I can use jQuery, and I found this :

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
```

but this is not exactly what I want.
i want some code like this :
[varzesh3](http://www.varzesh3.com/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: posting link to a very busy page with lots of content doesn't help anyone understand your issue. Suggest you go through the suite of jQueryUI interaction demos as starting point  http://jqueryui.com/ Then if you need help provide more specifics

Comment: sorry charlietfl.you are right!i can find solution with origin website : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your given example site http://www.varzesh3.com/ , you can use the jquery ui portlets below is the link hope it will help for you.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

Comment: very tnx for your help and hope